# Why do glossaries-extra package and bib2gls application give incorrect utf8 cyrillic characters?

Tags: pdftex, glossaries-extra, bib2gls

I do not know the origin of this problem and how to solve it. Does anybody can help me? Many thanks!
This is my working example (test.tex) of using glossaries-extra package and bib2gls with cyrillic (non-Latin) characters.

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage[T2A,T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english,russian]{babel}
\usepackage{substitutefont}
\substitutefont{T2A}{\familydefault}{Tempora-TLF}
\usepackage[record]{glossaries-extra}
\GlsXtrLoadResources[src={test-gloss}]

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\chapter{Sample}
Первое применение: \gls{zither}, \gls{shch-fish}.

Следующее применение: \gls{zither}, \gls{shch-fish}.
\printunsrtglossaries
\end{document}
```

The test-gloss.bib file containing the entries:

```
% Encoding = UTF-8
@index{zither, description={type of stringed musical instrument}}
@abbreviation{shch-fish, short={Щ},long={Щука}}
```

I expected to see something like this:
[image: correct character set]

but i have got incorrect cyrillic characters:
[image: incorrect character set]

nevertheless the file test.glg contains right encoding UTF-8:

```
bib2gls version 2.3 (2020-03-23)
Reading test.aux
TeX character encoding: UTF-8
Initialising resource test.glstex.
Parsing bib files for resource test.glstex.
Default encoding: not set
Reading test-gloss.bib
Cross-resource references allowed.
Processing resource test.glstex.
...
Encoding: UTF-8
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On windows I had to inform java that utf8 is wanted by setting an environment variable

```
   JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS="-Dfile.encoding=UTF8"
```

After this setting bib2gls reports:

```
Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: "-Dfile.encoding=UTF8"
bib2gls version 2.7 (2020-07-11)
Reading test-utf8.aux
Reading test-gloss.bib
```

and the glstex contains the correct utf8.

[image]

[image]